# Nodejs doesnt receive jsondata

Tags: node.js, post, fetch

My Node.js server is not able to send the data it receives back to the browser. It is able to send self-made data like this

```
app.post('/login', (req,res) =>{

  console.log(req.body);

  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.json({test: "test info",test2: "still testing"});//works
  //res.json(req.body);//does not work
})
```

In the fetch POST request, I have set the header 'Content-Type': 'application/json'.

In the firefox debugger, I can see that the information is sent via POST.[image]

I have tried stuff like

```
res.json(req.body);
res.json(req.body.pass);
res.json({pass:+req.body.pass});//response in browser -> {"pass":null}
res.json("{pass:"+req.body.pass+"}");//response in browser -> "{pass:undefined}"
```

Could someone tell me why the Node.js server doesn't receive the JSON data?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the [body-parser](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html)
? Otherwise express wont convert the body of the POST request to a JSON object that you can access with req.body.pass